# Arch Linux in Virtualbox keeps forgetting about my resolution

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, arch-linux, xfce

It's a fairly minor problem, but it's pretty annoying all the same. Whenever I start up Arch (DE is xfce) in VB, it always defaults to a small resolution *after* I login with slim, which uses the full resolution that the window allows it. I then have to change the size of the window to get it to fill it up again. Mint, my other VM, doesn't require me to do this.  Edit: I forgot to mention that I have installed the guest additions and have them set up as per the instructions on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier             "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier             "Device0"
  Driver                 "vboxvideo" # Choose the driver
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier             "Screen0"  
  Device                 "Device0"
  Monitor                "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth           24 # Choose the depth (16||24)
  SubSection             "Display"
    Depth                24
    Modes                "1280x720" # Choose the resolution
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

[More info here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg)